# Unable to validate certificate while enabling Client Certificate Authentication for nginx server

Tags: nginx, openssl, wget, client-certificates

I am very green when it comes to the world of servers and have been trying test out client certificate authentication in a bare bones nginx server. I generated the keys and certificate files using openssl based on this blog post verbatim: https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/

To summarize the openssl commands used:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -des3 -out user.key 4096
openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in user.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out user.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.pfx -inkey user.key -in user.crt -certfile ca.crt
```

However, no matter which way I try and hit this server, I can't seem to successfully validate via wget using the client certificate or firefox with the pfx file.

The wget command & response:

```
wget --ca-cert=user.crt --private-key=user.key 127.0.0.1:80
--2021-04-27 09:25:52--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-04-27 09:25:52 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

The nginx configuration file in question:

```
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  index    index.html;

  ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client_certs/ca.crt;
  ssl_verify_client on;

  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

  server {
    listen       80;
    root         html;

    location ~ / {
      if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
        return 403;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Oddly enough, removing the if statement toward the end seems to remove any validation, as I am able to access the html easily, regardless of ssl_verify_client being set to on or optional.
Any help would be very appreciated.